# How to avoid air bubbles while pipetting?

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, protocol

I get air bubbles while pipetting small volumes. How can I avoid them ?

Comment: You can try to be slow?

Comment: You have to pipet up slow and make sure your tip is (and stays) completely submerged in the solution. On the other hand it shouldn't be put in too far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're still pipetting too fast, you should move the piston slowly and evenly to avoid air bubbles. Also make sure that you wait a second or two for the liquid to rise before moving the tip out of the liquid reservoir.

Pipettes can also behave rather weird with any liquid that differs significantly in any physical property from water, e.g. very viscous solutions.

You can find a few more tips [in this document from Eppendorf](http://www.eppendorf.com/int/index.php?l=41&action=document&sitemap=1&docnode=53708) or [this one from Thermo Scientific](http://www.pipettecalibration.net/pipette-calibration-files/Guide-To-Pipetting-2.pdf).

Comment: Sometimes with very viscous liquids (such as detergent solutions), it may be necessary to slowly "rinse" the inside of the pipette by doing a full pieptte up and down of the liquid before an accurate amount will be drawn.